# fatal: Unable to read current working directory: No such file or directory. While on checkout branch same folder exists

Tags: git, github, gitlab, bitbucket

Cut down 2 branch release-a and release-b from release branch. both having the same folder structure. Suppose I am on branch release-b and current path is cicd_argocd/test-deployment/test and checkout to branch release-a. Now if i run any git command it wont work as it cane be seen in picture. but when change directory and come again on that directory and run git command it works. Any explanation for it.

```
demo-user@macbaby test % git branch
dev
master
release
release-a
* release-b
demo-user@macbaby test % pwd
/Users/uttu/Workspace/cicd_argocd/test-deployment/test
demo-user@macbaby test %
demo-user@macbaby test % git checkout release-a
Switched to branch
"release-a'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/release-a'
demo-user@macbaby test % pwd
/Users/uttu/Workspace/cicd_argocd/test-deployment/test
demo-user@macbaby test % git pull origin release-a
fatal: Unable to read current working directory: No such file or directory
demo-user@macbaby test %
demo-user@macbaby test % pwd
/Users/uttu/Workspace/cicd_argocd/test-deployment/test
demo-user@macbaby test % cd ..
demo-user@macbaby test-deployment % cd test
demo-user@macbaby test % git pull origin release-a
hint: Pulling without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is
hint: discouraged. You can squelch this message by running one of the following
hint: commands sometime before your next pull:
hint:
hint:
hint:
hint:
git config pull.rebase false
# merge (the default strategy)
git config pull.rebase true
# rebase
git config pull.ff only
# fast-forward only
hint:
hint: You can replace
"git config" with "git config
-global" to set a default
hint: preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase,
--no-rebase,
hint: or
-ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
hint: invocation.
Warning: Permanently added
'bitbucket.org'
(RSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

Comment: Please share your Pipeline.

Comment: @ycr : please go through it now. This seems git issue not pipeline issue.